# youtube embed three.js for multiple textures

Tags: youtube, three.js, embed

I'm trying to use this example ( http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_sandbox.html )
for adding a specifics youtube videos and webcam source as textures for planes.

Any quite specific code tips?
many thanks